# Is smoke chametz?

Tags: chametz-leaven

Let's say while people are burning chametz, (this is a public burning area where many people come to burn the chametz in a big pile) someone puts a grill over the smoke and puts a king salmon on the grill. Can he eat the salmon on Pesach or is the smoke considered chametz?

My assumptions: The smoke itself is not food. Also, when the person puts the grill on, the chametz stuff appears charred and pulverized to the point where no trace of its origin can be recognized. I.e., it's most likely unedible, but, of course, perhaps way down in the charred pile, maybe something didn't burn completely.

If it is chametz, explain why it is since the smoke itself is not an edible substance. Does chametz transfer in the air? (If it did, wouldn't smelling someone's exhaled breath be chametz?)

Comment: The critical point I think is one of bli’os, not one of Chametz gamur. Compare this to a case of cooking meat and milk in the same oven in two separate unwrapped trays. The whole thing is Basar b’Chalav, not because the smoke is edible but because it carries the taste. All the more so by chametz for which we’re more stringent!

Comment: @DonielF got the idea. But kouty makes a good point which I had thought of. I'm going to edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

First step of answer

Mishna Pesachim 2.1

> עבר זמנו, אסור בהנאתו, ולא יסיק בו תנור וכירים
>
> After the time of permitted to take advantage of the Chamets, they could not heat an oven.

Mishna Orla 3.4

> תבשיל שבשלו בקליפי ערלה, ידלק
>
> A dish cooked with barks of Orla needs to be burned

Rash

> ידלק כדאמר בפ' כל שעה (דף כו:) דיש שבח עצים בפת וכן בתבשיל יעלה באחד ומאתים
>
> As Gemara says in Pesachim 36b because the dough was ameliorated by woods.

But all this is only if there is profit from the isur when it's still not burned.(Tosfot Yom Tov in the name of Ran in the OP. cit. Mishna. Orla,, Gemara 26b).

Maybe permitted in your case. It depends if the smoke comes from a piece already entirely burned or not.

Regarding the taste of smoke. This is Hanaa achar beur, not prohibited.